# right aligned placeholder in <input>

Tags: html, css, formatting, placeholder

I have a text input that I want to be specifically for currency. Inside the text field, it should say [$Other      CAD]."$Other" should be aligned left and "CAD" should be aligned right, I currently just have a bunch of spaces between the "$Other" and the "CAD". This isn't ideal for different browsers, etc. Is there an easy way to get only the "CAD" portion of the placeholder to align right so it'll always fit regardless of the browser? Also, can I set two different text colors for the placeholder? For example, have the "$" and "CAD" in grey and the "Other" in black

```html
<style>
  .donation-amount-input {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 34px;
  }
  .form-control::placeholder {
    font-size: 34px;
  }
  #S {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 36px;
    padding-left: 10px
  }
  #Other {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 36px;
    padding-left: 35px;
  }
  #CAD {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 36px;
    padding-left: 40%;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <p onclick="fakePlaceholder()" id="S">$</p>
  <p onclick="fakePlaceholder()" id="Other">Other</p>
  <p onclick="fakePlaceholder()" id="CAD">CAD</p>
  <input 
  type="text" 
  onselect="fakePlaceholder()"
  class="form-control donation-amount-input" 
  id="other-amount"
  />
</body>
<script>
  function fakePlaceholder() {
    var S = document.querySelector('S');
    S.style.display = 'none';
    var Other = document.querySelector('Other');
    Other.style.display = 'none';
    var CAD = document.querySelector('CAD');
    CAD.style.display = 'none';
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can't do that with a placeholder**, you will have to create a fake one with javascript for the effect. You have to add three elements : one for the `$`, one for `Other` and one for `CAD`. Then you can styles them and positioning them with `position: absolute;` in the input to create a fake placeholder. ( Don't forget: you can't put html elements in an input, so you will have to wrap the input and the three elements into another element so you position everything according to it ).

After that, you will have to use javascript to hide this fake placeholder when someone clicks or moves with keyboard on it.

Try something, and if you need help, come back here and show us your code.

Comment: Thanks for the hint